# Recursive algorithm fails to complete tests in allotted time

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, binary, tomography-reconstruction

I was doing a test that required an algorithm for Binary Tomography. A set of 38 test values are supplied that test correctness, but there is also a time limit of 1 CPU sec to complete all the tests. The problem is as follows:

Output “Yes” if there exists an m-by-n matrix A, with each element either being 0 or 1, such that

[image: ∑j=1nAi,j=ri∀i∈{1,2,…,m} and ∑i=1mAi,j=cj∀j∈{1,2,…,n}.]

Otherwise output “No”.

For each test, 2 arrays are provided:

1. *r* (the sum of each row in the matrix)
2. *c* (the sum of each column in the matrix)

In the equation:

- *m* is the length of the *r* array, where *1 <= m*
- *n* is the length of the *c* array, where *n <= 1000*
- *ri* is an element of *r*, where *0 <= ri <= n*
- *cj* is an element of *c*, where *0 <= cj <= m*

**A "Yes" example**

m = 3;
n = 4;
r = [2, 3, 2];
c = [1, 1, 3, 2];

[image]

**A "No" example**

m = 3;
n = 3;
r = [0, 0, 3];
c = [0, 0, 3];

I have a solution that appears to give correct answers, however it only manages 12 / 38 tests before the 1 second of CPU time is exceeded.

I originally wrote the code in ES5 and then went back and converted to to ES3 to try and get more performance out of it. (originally managed 9 tests as ES5). There doesn't seem a great deal left that I can do to the current algorithm to improve the performance (unless I am mistaken). This leads me to believe that my algorithm is at fault an that there must be a faster algorithm for doing this. I did a ton of reading trying to find one and ended up with a headache :)

So I'm turning to the community to see if anyone can suggest a faster algorithm than I am currently using.

```js
'use strict';

const ZEROS = (function (seed) {
  let string = seed;
  for (let i = 0; i < 19; i += 1) {
    string += seed;
  }

  return string;
}('00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'));

const ZEROSLEN = ZEROS.length;

const permutate = function (n, ri) {
  const result = [];
  const memoize = {};
  let count = 0;
  do {
    const bin = count.toString(2);
    if (ZEROSLEN + bin.length > ZEROSLEN + n) {
      break;
    }

    if (!memoize[bin] && (bin.split('1').length - 1) === ri) {
      const string = (ZEROS + bin).slice(-n);
      const sLen = string.length;
      const perm = new Array(sLen);
      for (let i = sLen - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
        perm[i] = +string[i];
      }

      memoize[bin] = result.push(perm);
    }

    count += 1;
  } while (count);

  return result;
};

const getMatrixSum = function (n, matrix) {
  const mLength = matrix.length;
  const rows = new Array(mLength);
  const a = new Array(n);
  const last = mLength - 1;
  for (let x = n - 1; x >= 0; x -= 1) {
    for (let y = last; y >= 0; y -= 1) {
      rows[y] = matrix[y][x];
    }

    let sum = 0;
    for (let i = rows.length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
      sum += rows[i];
    }

    a[x] = sum;
  }

  return a;
};

const isEqual = function (a, b) {
  const length = a.length;
  if (length !== b.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (let i = length - 1; i >= 0; i -= 1) {
    if (a[i] !== b[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
};

const addRow = function (i, prev, r, c, result) {
  if (result) {
    return result;
  }

  const n = c.length;
  const ri = r[i];
  if (ri < 0 || ri > n) {
    throw new RangeError('ri out of range');
  }

  const p = permutate(n, ri);
  const m = r.length;
  const rsLast = m - 1;
  const nextI = i + 1;
  for (let x = p.length - 1; x >= 0; x -= 1) {
    const permutation = p[x];
    const next = prev.slice();
    next.push(permutation);
    const sums = getMatrixSum(n, next);
    if (i < rsLast) {
      let memo = 0;
      for (let j = sums.length - 1; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
        if (sums[j] > c[j]) {
          memo += 1;
        }
      }

      if (!memo && addRow(nextI, next, r, c, result)) {
        return true;
      }
    } else if (isEqual(sums, c)) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
};

const isSolvable = function (r, c) {
  const m = r.length;
  const n = c.length;
  if (m < 1 || n > 1000) {
    throw new Error('Bad data');
  }

  for (let j = n; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
    const cj = c[j];
    if (cj < 0 || cj > m) {
      throw new RangeError('cj out of range');
    }
  }
  
  return addRow(0, [], r, c, false) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
};

console.log(isSolvable([2, 3, 2], [1, 1, 3, 2]));

console.log(isSolvable([0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3]));
```

It may be worth noting that the tests are being run on SpiderMonkey version JavaScript-C24.2.0

Refs:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_tomography

https://open.kattis.com/problems/tomography

Comment: Your `permutate` function does a bunch of inefficient but unnecessary operations. Try to optimise it, if necessary without using Array builtins.

Comment: As simple as I can put it, it gets permutations for row and column and then brute force tries those against one another to see if a matrix can be formed. But I was thinking that there must be a non-brute force way. But maybe my code is just that insufficient.

Comment: it looks like a test for a [Nonogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonogram).

Comment: It is certainly related.

Comment: Well at least don't just brute force it.. while still not great, branching on the cells allows you to simultaneously apply the horizontal and vertical constraints so you can prune a lot (while permuting has the effect of pruning by only considering either the horizontal or the vertical constraints, not both).

Comment: @Bergi I guess you mean the `reverse`, It was something that I tried because bignumber.js library suggested that they had faster results on small arrays using this method rather than using `shift`s and `unshift`s. I actually didn't notice and difference.

Comment: @Xotic750 Yes, that combined with the fact that you `slice` the `arr` anyway. Rather try working with indices only that represent the rotation, and create the new arrays accordingly.

Comment: My initial thought from the back of my head (which most of the time turns out to be worthwhile)... I would start this job by limiting the matrix size to `rmax` by `cmax` and and start crossing up rows and columns from the biggest `r` and `c` values in an orderly fashion up until i can not any more then grow the matrix size by 1 on the row and column and proceed forward. I am pretty sure this would be a sensible way to start.

Comment: Or.. of course we can start with a `rmin` by `cmin` matrix and simply fill it up and grow the matrix size by 1 on rows and columns (as long as the limits allow) and proceed testing to insert the next `r` and `c` values. Unlike in my previous comment, this time in an ascending order fashion. So best start with sorted `r` and `c` values. This is also very sensible since you start with a minimal problem and solve the rest gradually by building up on your previous solution. Like a dynamical programming task.

Comment: @Redu "orderly fashion" and "simply fill up" doesn't work. You have multiple choices were to place a bit, and not all will work. You'd need to do backtracking.

Comment: I've been taking a look at permutation generators, was trying to find a Heap's Algorithm that produces only unique permutations for binary array's, but haven't found anything great yet.

Comment: I have an improved (I believe) permutations routine, things get a little further but it still fails the allotted time. Creating permutations for this kind of brute-force just takes far too long (when the r and c length increase marginally).

Comment: You can try [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)?

Comment: Thankyou all for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't have this ready for my test, but I found a far more efficient algorithm after the event.

```js
'use strict';

const sortNumber = function (a, b) {
  return b - a;
};

const isSolvable = function (r, c) {
  const m = r.length;
  const n = c.length;
  if (m < 1 || n > 1000) {
    throw new Error('Bad data');
  }

  for (let j = n; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
    const cj = c[j];
    if (cj < 0 || cj > m) {
      throw new RangeError('cj out of range');
    }
  }

  while (r.length) {
    c.sort(sortNumber);
    const ri = r.pop();
    if (ri < 0 || ri > n) {
      throw new RangeError('ri out of range');
    }

    if (ri) {
      if (!c[ri - 1]) {
        return 'No';
      }

      for (let j = ri - 1; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
        c[j] -= 1;
      }
    }
  }

  for (let j = n - 1; j >= 0; j -= 1) {
    if (c[j]) {
      return 'No';
    }
  }

  return 'Yes';
};

console.log(isSolvable([2, 3, 2], [1, 1, 3, 2]));

console.log(isSolvable([0, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3]));
```

Answer (score 2):

Since permutations yield to brute force, they should be the last resort when developing algorithms similar to this one. Most of the time they are not needed.

As i have commented above, I have a feeling that one strategy could be first sorting the `r` and `c` arrays descending and start with the bigger ones. I haven't had time to implemented a JS code to work out this, so I haven't had a chance to test thoroughly. Please have a look and if you discover a flaw please mention.

In the below visual representation of the algorithm we try  `r = [1,3,1,3]` and `c = [3,2,1,2]`. `X` denotes an occupied cell and a red dot denotes an untouchable cell while the empty ones are obviously the free cells. So in the real algorithm to represent a cell we need a data type like `{value: false, avail: false}` for a red dot while `{value: false, avail: true}` would mean a free space. Or to save space and speed you may use a data type like `0b00` for red dot, `0b01` for free space and `0b1X` for occupied (X here means don't care) cells.

[image]

**Note:** It's worth mentioning Step 3 where we process `c[0]`. After we insert the three `X`s we have to check the rows occupied by the `X`s to update the status of the empty cells in those rows. In this case for r[2], all empty cells become untouchable.

**Edit:**

Well.. OK since we don't need to construct the solution in a 2D array like structure but only need an answer on wheather the supplied data is meaningful or not, I have come up with another and simpler idea which is essentially based on the above approach. I really don't think it can get any faster than this. It solves a 999 by 1000 board in like 50ms.

Lets get into it.

1. The input is `r = [2, 3, 2]; c = [1, 1, 3, 2];` However one important condition here is **both `c` and `r` arrays should sum up to the same number**. We can simply check this at the beginning of our code or leave it, go through the following steps and if they pass check only if `c` is full of 0s. The following code prefers the latter approach.
2. Sort `r` descending so; `r = [3, 2, 2]; c = [1, 1, 3, 2];`
3. Try reducing `r[0]` (3 in the first case) many non-zero elements of `c` by 1. Now `c` becomes `[0, 0, 2, 2]`. If it fails then try no more and return `false`.
4. Now that we have finished with row `r[0]`, recursivelly call function with `r = [2, 2]; c = [0, 0, 2, 2];` while `r.length` is bigger than 0 and the bool argument `b` is `true`. Next call will be `r = [2]; c = [0, 0, 1, 1];` and finally `r = []; c = [0, 0, 0, 0];`
5. If finally a recursive call with empty `r` is invoked then check `b` is `true` and all items of `c` are `0`. (`b && cs.every(n => !n)`).

I believe this is just fine but as i don't have your test cases it's for you to try. I am sure it will pass the time test though. Here is the code in it's simplest. Here i am testing `rs = [7,3,5,4,6,2,8]` and `cs = [7,1,6,3,4,5,2,7]`. It looks like;

```
  71634527
7 x xxxxxx
3 x x    x
5 x x xx x
4 x x  x x
6 x xxxx x
2 x      x
8 xxxxxxxx
```

```js
function nonogram(rs,cs){
  function runner(rs,cs, b = true){//console.log(rs,cs,b)
    return b && rs.length ? runner(rs.slice(1),                                 // rows argument
                                   cs.map(e => rs[0] ? e ? (b = !--rs[0], e-1)  // cols argument
                                                         : e
                                                     : e),
                                   b)                                           // bool argument
                          : b && cs.every(n => !n);
  }
return runner(rs.sort((a,b) => b-a), cs);
}

var rs = [7,3,5,4,6,2,8],
    cs = [7,1,6,3,4,5,2,7],
    result;
console.time("test");
result = nonogram(rs,cs);
console.timeEnd("test");
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thankyou for sharing your algorithm thoughts. If you should like to try any code you produce for this algorithm then I added a link to the online test. https://open.kattis.com/problems/tomography

Comment: @Xotic750 Thank you.. I guess it would be fun to implement this in JS but only after i have some free time. I am curious to see if this would pass the 38 tests limit for the given max matrix sizes.

Comment: @Xotic750 Well after like 9 months i have added a code. It's based on my initial idea but simplified and should be super efficient. I believe it should work yet i don't have your test cases so it is up to you to test and let me know how it is.

Comment: @Xotic750 I have checked the case but couldn't find 38 different samples. When the given 2 samples are applied they both resolve in 0ms both with V8 and SpiderMonkey. When i repeat them 38 times in a for loop V8 results 0ms SpiderMonkey results 2ms in average. 1000x1000 board gives a `true` result in like 40ms average. `false` results are of course much faster since they stop prematurely. If the algorithm is correct (which i will test later) this is for sure the fastest by a large margin among JS solutions listed there. You can fork it at https://repl.it/@redu/Nonogram-Solver and play.

Comment: They don't give you the samples, they are hidden. You submit your answer and they just tell you if it passes or fails and the time it took. You have to vreate an account though.